# Primary decomposition of $(0)$ in $k[x,y,z]∕(xyz-z^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm thinking about this problem:

> Let $k$ be a field and $A:=k[x,y,z]∕(xyz-z^2)$.
>
> $1)$ Show that $(\overline{x})$ and $(\overline{y})$ are primary and that $(\overline{z})$ is prime in $A$.
>
> $2)$ Find a minimal primary decomposition of $(\overline{0})$ in $A$.

I already know how to solve $1)$, but I'm stuck with $2)$.

From the way the question is posed, it looks like the decomposition is supposed to be something like $(\overline{0})=(\overline{x})\cap(\overline{y})\cap(\overline{z})\cap...$

But my first thought was to try $(\overline{0})=(\overline{xy-z})\cap(\overline{z})$.

First, we have:

$\overline{f}\overline{g}\in(\overline{xy-z})\implies fg=s(xy-z)+t(xyz-z^2)\in(xy-z)\implies fg\in(xy-z)\overset{(*)}{\implies}$ $f\in(xy-z)$ or $g\in(xy-z)\implies \overline{f}\in(\overline{xy-z})$ or $\overline{g}\in(\overline{xy-z})$.

therefore $(\overline{xy-z})$ is prime in $A$ (where $^{(*)}$ is because $xy-z$ is irreducible in $k[x,y,z]$).

Second, if $\overline{p}\in(\overline{xy-z})\cap(\overline{z})$, then $p=q(xy-z)+r(xyz-z^2)$ and $p=rz+s(xyz-z^2)$, therefore

$$q(xy-z)=rz+s(xyz-z^2)-r(xyz-z^2)\in(z)$$
$$\Rightarrow q\in(z)\Rightarrow p\in(xyz-z^2)\Rightarrow\overline{p}=\overline{0}$$

So, indeed, $(\overline{0})=(\overline{xy-z})\cap(\overline{z})$, and I didn't need either $(\overline{x})$ or $(\overline{y})$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Equivalently, you have to decompose $(xyz-z^2)$ in $k[x,y,z]$. What's your first guess?

Comment: Isn't $(xyz-z^2)=(xy-z)\cap(z)$ a valid decomposition?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.